# How to get list of assets/rooms/floors, spaces in Revit files from forge viewer

Tags: autodesk-forge, forge

we can get asset properties sure. But we need to collect all the names of equipment or rooms or floors etc.

Please help on this, where to get all equipment from the Revit file using forge viewer.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

The [Forge Model Derivative](https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/model-derivative/v2/developers_guide/overview) service typically extracts all the metadata that is somehow related to individual "physical" elements present in your design. Unfortunately, when there's metadata that is not related to any specific element, it will most likely not be extracted.

In those special cases, you can use the [Forge Design Automation](https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/design-automation/v3/developers_guide/overview/) service to basically run Revit in the cloud, open your RVT/IFC design there, and use your custom Revit API plugin to extract the information you need yourself.